# Trying to use /^\s*$/ match multiple blank lines and replace them failed and get a confusing result

Tags: regex, perl

Perl version : 5.16.01

I'm reading a book about regex which based on perl 5.8

The book said that `s/^\s*$/blabla/mg`  can match and replace multiple blank lines. 
But when I praticed, I got a confusing result.

```
code:
$text = "c\n\n\n\n\nb";
$text =~ s/^\s*$/<p>/mg;
print "$text";
```

Here is the result:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\regex>perl t2h.pl 
c
<p><p>
b
```

I want to know  why I didn't get a single `<p>` but double between 'c' and 'b'. Does Perl's `/$/` change after 5.8 ?

Answer (score 4):

The lesson here is be wary of regular expressions that will match a zero-width pattern, you could get unexpected results.

We can see what's happening here by showing the prematch, match and post match of both replacements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "c\n\n\n\nb";

$text =~ s{^\s*$}{
    printf qq{<"%s" - "%s" - "%s">\n}, map s/\n/\\n/gr, ($`, $&, $');
    "<p>"
}emg;

$text =~ s/\n/\\n/g;
print qq{Result: "$text"};
```

Outputs `<"Prematch" - "Match" - "Postmatch">`:

```
<"c\n" - "\n\n" - "\nb">
<"c\n\n\n" - "" - "\nb">
Result: "c\n<p><p>\nb"
```

Basically, the regex matches from position 2 until 4, capturing 2 return characters.  After that replacement it starts searching from position 4 and matches a zero width pattern, so adds a second `<p>`.

One of the reasons this isn't intuitive is because our regex has replaced the `\n\n` at positions 2 & 3 with a `<p>`.  However, lookbehind assertions (which `^` is special variant) treat the string as it originally was, not as it might have been replaced by previous passes of a `/g` regex.  Therefore when matching at position 4, the regex sees `c\n\n\n` behind it instead of `c\n<p>` (as demonstrated in our output above), and therefore will match `^` again and `$` immediately in front of it with no spacing between.

The solution to this is to not allow zero width patterns by using `+` in this instance instead of `*`.

**Secondary Example**

Another example of this is the following, simpler regex

```
my $text = "caab";

$text =~ s/a*/<p>/g;
print $text;
```

Outputs:

```
<p>c<p><p>b<p>
```

The positional breakdown of this matching is as follows:

```
0 c - match a zero width pattern
1 a - Match a 2 character pattern
2 a
3 b  - Match a zero width pattern
4 $ - match a zero width pattern
```

Therefore, the final lesson is to simply be wary of regexes that will match a zero width pattern.

Comment: Re "I don't know why it's doing this", Why wouldn't it? You asked it to match zero (or more) whitespace chars starting at `b`, so it did. (Then you told it to do it again, and it said "nah-hah, I don't match the same thing twice", so it looked beyond `b`.)

Comment: @ikegami THAT is not an explanation.  When I ask something to count how many hands I have, I understandably expect the answer to be 2.  I do not expect the answer to be 2 and 0 and 0 and 0 and 0.  Yes, both are true, but the second is superfluous.  I do welcome a real explanation concerning the logic behind this though.

Comment: You didn't ask the count hands, you asked to replace the 0+ spaces starting at position 3. Turns out that it can indeed match there, so it replaces the match as you asked.

Comment: Counting hands would be `"habah" =~ /h/g`, not `"habah" =~ /h*/g`

Comment: Okay, I'm willing to get on board.  The explanation is that it's positional matching.  First it matches at position 0, then 1, then 3, and finally 4.  Even though positions 1 and 3 end up being adjacent, they still match because the regex allows zero width patterns.

Comment: I'm even willing to get on board with the original regex as well.  I suppose the lesson here is to be careful of zero width patterns that match, as if you're replacing them with anything then could get unexpected results.  I'll edit my answer in a bit with additional information.

Comment: That's a clever pattern for debugging regular expressions.

Comment: @Miller, your answer is really helpful.would u mind giving me a example which shows the procedure of using s/^\s*$/<p>/g(don't miss '^' and '$') for matching "c\n\n\n\nb" as the second example does?

Comment: @Sisox I've added another paragraph to explain the search and replacement of the original regex.

Answer (score 0):

Quantifier * match 0 or more times,
quantifier ? match 1 or more times.

So your regex should be written as `s/^\s+$/<p>/mg`

Comment: Thank u for ur answer , but I just want to know why there are double '<p>'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$text = "c\n\n\n\n\nb";
$text =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
print $text;
```

***DEMO*** http://ideone.com/WmVFHz